# Cannot load GPX file via Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, gpx

I am needing to load in a GPX file to my Android Emulator, however when I click "LOAD GPX/KML", nothing happens.

I am running MacOS Catalina; sometimes a loading wheel shows up for a few seconds but still nothing happens. I even try dragging the GPX file there and still nothing.
[image]

Any idea why I can't load a GPX file into my Android Emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a bug on the Catalina beta. Updated the OS and it works fine now